# How do i know on which row was clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have  table which contains the rows that are dynamic from server side scripting(PHP) 
and also using Zend Framework .
So each row will have hyperlink with id 
     SOmevalue(Dynamic)
now each row will have contextmenu (Jquery Plugin ) appended to each row by the below code.

```
    $("#myTable td:first-child").contextMenu("myMenu1",{
      bindings: {
            'hdr': function(t) {
                alert($("#Test0").attr("data-value1"));
                alert($("#Test0").attr("data-value2"));

             }
      },
      menuStyle: {
            border: '1px solid #000'
       }
      });
```

So My Problem is how do i know on which row was context menu clicked and 
suppose if i click on second row i want to get the value of that < a href> 
value of that "test1" or "test2" or "test3" or "test4"
dynamically . i should not able to write "test1"or test2 son on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the html markup that gets generated.
Something along these lines should work:

```
$("#myTable td:first-child").contextMenu("myMenu1", {
    bindings: {
        'hdr': function(t) {
            alert($("this").closest("tr").find("a").attr("href"));
        }
    },
    menuStyle: {
        border: '1px solid #000'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

AS with most jQuery event handlers, my guess is that the `this` variable will be the element that was clicked.  Regardless, if you can at least get the element that was clicked, the rest should be easy.

Check out the `closest()`method in the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

I'm just guessing here, but you could do something like 
 
`var value = $(this).closest("a.someClass").attr("data-value1");` where "someClass" is optional but would help to make sure you got the right anchor tag if there were potentially others in the same row.